# What is the difference between parece and pareciera?

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, uso-de-palabras, verbos, tiempos-verbales

What is the difference between *parece que* and *pareciera que*? How are both normally translated? What tenses can be used after *pareciera que*, and in general how is *pareciera* used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **Parece que**  —  **It appears that**
- **Pareciera que** — **It would appear that**

Basically it's used to make sentence less assertive.

Comment: What tense would be used after "Pareciera que"?  Past (imperfect) subjunctive?  Would it be "Pareciera que tuvieras la respuesta correcta"? (It would appear that you have the correct answer.)

Comment: Present simple, just like in your English translation. "Pareciera que tienes la respuesta correcta"

Answer (score 4):

El tiempo condicional o pospretérito se suele usar por cortesía o para expresar opinión o probabilidad. Por ejemplo, “me gustaría” en vez de “me gusta”, “querría” en vez de “quiero”, etc.

Por otro lado, el tiempo condicional suele conjugarse como el pretérito imperfecto del subjuntivo. Mucha gente dice “quisiera pedirle un favor” en vez de “querría ...”.

Combinando ambos, tenemos que “parecería que” o “pareciera que” es una variante menos asertiva de “parece que”.

Comment: Técnicamente, en casos como «quisiera» o «pareciera», no hablamos ni del condicional ni del pretérito imperfecto del subjuntivo sino del pluscuamperfecto simple del indicativo.  Es por esta razón que no es posible el uso con las formas de *-se-* (solo con *-ra-*